# Installation of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Beta and Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: installation, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

Has anybody tried to install the beta SP1 for VS2010 and MVC3 at the same time? Is it safe to install, or is it better to wait for the RTM of the SP1? I remember reading something about issues with MVC3 RC2 and SP1 Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with VS2010 SP1 beta and MVC 3 RC (what became RC1 - they were only planning one RC until this problem came up) that affected Razor Intellisense.  This was resolved by a second RC release of MVC 3.  There is no issue with MVC 3 RTM and VS 2010 SP1 beta.

[Source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioExplosionVS2010SP1BETAReleasedAndContext.aspx) - see "Beta Caveats"

Answer (score 1):

I have these installed and no issue for me.