# Will Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (beta) break asp.net MVC 3 (RTM)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got VS 2010 (no service pack) and asp.net MVC 3 installed.  I would like to try out the VS2010 SP1 beta but afraid that it will break my MVC 3 projects.

Does anyone know if i can install SP1 beta right on top of MVC 3 RTM?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is being discussed here:
[Installation of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Beta and Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794227/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta-and-asp-net-mvc-3)